# Best timing method in Python?

Tags: python, time, variable-assignment, difference, seconds

I need it for my assignment ,its my first time with computer science .please anyone help with this one.
question.****Type a return statement: "return " followed by the expression that performs the calculation described in the table above. (Remember that the return statement is used to give a value back to the caller of the function.)
def seconds_difference(time_1, time_2):****
    """ (number, number) -> number

```
Return the number of seconds later that a time in seconds

time_2 is than a time in seconds time_1.

>>> seconds_difference(1800.0, 3600.0)
1800.0
>>> seconds_difference(1800.0, 3600.0)
-1800.0
>>> seconds_difference(1800.0, 2160.0)
360.0
>>> seconds_difference(1800.0, 1800.0)
0.0
"""
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free homework plagiarism service.

Comment: so how can i get help

Comment: Your textbook, Google, your teacher, your classmates, hard work...

Comment: i am doing an online course and they are not responding and have no one else who can help i know i should be doing it myself but i tried I dropped coruse of CS before because online course mentors dont help

Comment: @nida82 Perhaps look into a [code mentor](https://www.codementor.io/get-help-now)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wish you the best of luck in your class.  Here's some help:

```
def seconds_difference(first, second):
    return second - first

print(seconds_difference(1800.0, 2160.0))
```

You should really read about functions:

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

Comment: While I think its nice your trying to help the OP by answering his question, providing an answer encourages other low-quality "homework questions". I think a better idea would be to point him/her in the right direction where they can find quality resources to learn from. In other words, [teach him to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, opinion-based, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.

Comment: You seem to be posting one to two _dozen_ answers per day. It would be nice if you reconsidered posting answers that would merit the above comment.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  I really enjoy homework... I know it sounds lame but I guess I am kind of crippling them, sorry.